# Not Getting the "MAP Route"

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

Why I am not Getting the "MAP Route", whats the issue with this code. Or, Kindly provide me the code for "Getting Route on Map"

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView,
                 calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {

    let selectedLoc = view.annotation

    print("Annotation '\(String(describing: selectedLoc?.title!))' has been selected")

    let currentLocMapItem = MKMapItem.forCurrentLocation()

    let selectedPlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: (selectedLoc?.coordinate)!, addressDictionary: nil)
    let selectedMapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: selectedPlacemark)

    let mapItems = [selectedMapItem, currentLocMapItem]

    let launchOptions = [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving]

    MKMapItem.openMaps(with: mapItems, launchOptions:launchOptions)
}
```

Comment: You need create a route between 2 designated points?

Comment: @ReinierMelian may i provide you the whole code, just two files ?

Comment: When i click on accessoryview, route should be come in map controller, but it doest not appear

Comment: yes please provide your code

Comment: @ReinierMelian brother, here is the link of small project. (implementing nearBy places i.e nearby Banks, nearby Gas station) kindly check..
all things are fine.. just map route is not being shown,
kindly check what is missing

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PPOj80NeHHofUPrjd35dtJSQAMs2dq_f/view

Comment: ok I will review it and I will drop something to you brother

Comment: Bundle of Thanks  bro, I am extremely waiting for you, May God bless you

Comment: Sorry yesterday I was so busy but now I am reviewing it, anyway what you need is a route between 2 points? right?

Comment: No, I want the route between my current location and the pin i selected on map... I mean to say, whatever pin I select.. it shows  its information in accessoryView... when i click on accessoryView... map route should be shown... but it does't appear

Comment: @ReinierMelian bro, just because of this issue, twice times AppStore rejected my app.... due to minimal functionality...

Comment: ok I will help you, but your appstore rejection maybe is not related to this issue

Comment: Your app does something else besides search the path between your location and another?

Comment: Kindly run the app, you will come to know whats the real issue... when click on accessoryView to find path.... it shows "Directions are not available" this is the actual isseu

Comment: Did you execute the app ? kindly run this on real device iPhone,

Comment: Yes, we can chat about this?

Comment: Your app is opening Maps app with your 2 locations I think is better to create the route in your app itself

Comment: I will post your code fixed on a github repo @AbdulJabbar

Comment: @ReinierMelian bro
this code only work for apple default location not for custom or current location
if I add Custom Location through Simulator > Debug > Location > Custom location OR When i run it on real device iPhone, then its shows this alertbox.. mean no map-route no direction, but if i run it on simulator by using default APPLE location, then it location map route and directions.. which is not useful whats its solution –

Comment: I will check it again

Comment: From what position are you trying to create route? can you give me the aproximate location?

Comment: Brother,
I just want the map-route between user's current location and the pin he selected (accessoryView)

Comment: the code you have provided me, kindly run it on iPhone, you will get my point

Comment: @ReinierMelian bro, thats my point

Comment: please run this app on iPhone , app running on simulator, it does't pick current location, it picks Apple default location,if I add Custom Location through Simulator > Debug > Location > Custom location OR When i run it on real device iPhone, then its shows this alertbox.. mean no map-route no direction,

Comment: Yes but from what position are you trying to get route? you must be at least in the united States to get a valid route, can you share your test current location?

Comment: Its not a good approach :( why only limited for USA ? 
i want that it should pick current location, every where in the world
and make a route between current location and the pin (accessoryView) one selects

Comment: when it is showing nearby location with respect to user's current location.. then why not route ??
@ReinierMelian please

Comment: Man your annotations are in SF California, so if you are in another part of the world you can't get any route

Comment: how can i change my annotations :( annotations should be according to current state

Comment: Brother is there any solution.. that it should work every where according to current location...
@ReinierMelian 
I have to submit one project on AppStore, but just because of this minimal functionality, i can't
please provide any solution..

Comment: Man for me your app work just fine, in mi iphone, I get the stations of services around of mee and I can get route from mi position to those stations

Comment: But why it is just limited to USA... because of annotations etc ? how can it be generalize... I mean it should work everywhere, not just in USA
@ReinierMelian

Comment: Man I live in Barcelona and the app work just fine I can provide image if you want to

Comment: did you finally get this working?

Comment: No Brother :( @ReinierMelian
Don't know why is it not working? I have tried my best as i could.. but don't know whats the thing is missing..

Comment: are you using this code https://github.com/rmelian2014/MapRouteQuestion ???

Comment: Because of this missing functionality, my app is being rejected from AppStore due to minimal functionality :(
@ReinierMelian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had added this method to create a map route between 2 `MKMapItem`

```
func createRouteTo(fromMapItem: MKMapItem,selectedMapItem: MKMapItem) {

    if(CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid(self.mapview.userLocation.coordinate) && CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid(selectedMapItem.placemark.coordinate))
    {
        self.showLoading(message: "Creando Ruta...")
        let directionRequest = MKDirectionsRequest()
        directionRequest.source = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: fromMapItem.placemark.coordinate, addressDictionary: nil))
        directionRequest.destination = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: selectedMapItem.placemark.coordinate, addressDictionary: nil))
        directionRequest.transportType = .automobile
        directionRequest.requestsAlternateRoutes = false

        // Calculate the direction
        let directions = MKDirections(request: directionRequest)

        directions.calculate { [unowned self] (directionResponse, error) in
            self.hideLoading(withDelay: 0.1)
            guard let response = directionResponse else {
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error: \(error)")
                    let alert = UIAlertController.init(title:"Error Creando Ruta",
                                                       message:error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Aceptar", style: .destructive, handler:nil))
                    self.present(alert, animated:true , completion:nil)
                }

                return
            }

            if(self.currentRouteOverlay != nil)
            {
                self.mapview.remove(self.currentRouteOverlay!)
            }

            let route = response.routes[0]
            self.currentRouteOverlay = route.polyline
            self.mapview.add(route.polyline, level: .aboveRoads)

            let rect =  route.polyline.boundingMapRect
            self.mapview.setVisibleMapRect(rect, edgePadding: UIEdgeInsetsMake(15, 15, 15, 15), animated: true)
        }
    }

}
```

this is your method modified

```
// This method will be called when we will tap on the annotation for Details.Then it will open in new View and make a route from current location to selected location.
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView,
                 calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {

        let selectedLoc = view.annotation

        print("Annotation '\(String(describing: selectedLoc?.title!))' has been selected")

        let currentLocMapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: mapView.userLocation.coordinate))

        let selectedPlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: (selectedLoc?.coordinate)!, addressDictionary: nil)
        let selectedMapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: selectedPlacemark)

        self.createRouteTo(fromMapItem:currentLocMapItem, selectedMapItem: selectedMapItem)
    }
```

full code here https://github.com/rmelian2014/MapRouteQuestion

[image]

Comment: Bro thanks a lot, I really appreciate your efforts but i am not finding the output what i want, neither map-route is being shown nor directions..

Comment: kindly check this link . when i tap on accessroyView to get route between my location and desired location, this alert box shown and nothing more          https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VuRT_FFprvy6IGVzYMV3Nz-_l8-IsznK

Comment: Whats the thing which is missed ? :(

Comment: if I add Custom Location through Simulator > Debug > Location > Custom location OR  When i run it on real device iPhone, then its shows this alertbox.. mean no map-route no direction,
but if i run it on simulator by using default  APPLE location, then it location map route and directions.. which is not useful
whats its solution